# what is the length of a language that contains epsilon?

Tags: formal-languages

1, I have an NFA that can recognize two words, "aa" and "epsilon".
So the language L1 this NFA recognizes is a set {aa, epsilon}.
What is the length of this language?
Is |L1| = 1? or |L1| = 2?

2, Assuming I have another NFA that can recognize one word "aa".
So the language L will be a set {aa}
In formal language, epsilon belongs to every language.
Thus in fact L2 contains epsilon, that is a set {aa, epsilon}
So what is the lenght of this language L2? 1 or 2?

Thanks

Comment: This question would be closed there as being too elementary. Maybe they'd take it on Math?

Comment: AHA, I don't know what they would like to do and where they'd like to take. As I cannot find the answer from Google, I just asked this simple question here. Hope this won't bother others.

Comment: Oops, misunderstood~ Definitely this question would be close in cstheory.stackexchange.com, because it's too elementary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The length of a language is the cardinality of the set. Cardinality refers to how many elements the set contains. L1 contains two strings. Ergo...
2. Not every language contains epsilon. You're probably thinking of the "empty set" which is different from "epsilon", the "empty string". The size of the empty set is zero, and it is a subset of L2. The set containing only epsilon is of size one and is not a subset of L2. L2 contains one string, so it's length is...

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I do also think so, but just cannot make sure. That will help a lot

Comment: I think you understood what I mean. Before I post my question, I have already thought about it, but just cannot make sure. What you said is right. BTW, I have accepted it. I just begin to use stackoverflow and don't how to use it. Is that all the things I need to do?

Comment: You're all set. Good question, and thanks for giving the problem some thought ahead of time. Welcome to SO!